# Parsing facebook graph api response partly working

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been trying to parse the response from Facebook graph API, and it's partly working.

The response returns the following:

```
Facebook\GraphObject Object
(
    [backingData:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 448835061804426_813332478688014
                    [from] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [category] => Software
                            [name] => Gibbo 2D - Game Engine
                            [id] => 448835061804426
                        )

                    [story] => Gibbo 2D - Game Engine likes a link.
                    [story_tags] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 448835061804426
                                            [name] => Gibbo 2D - Game Engine
                                            [offset] => 0
                                            [length] => 22
                                            [type] => page
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [privacy] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [value] => 
                        )

                    [type] => status
                    [created_time] => 2014-10-31T11:10:49+0000
                    [updated_time] => 2014-10-31T11:10:49+0000
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 448835061804426_809773115710617
                    [from] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [category] => Software
                            [name] => Gibbo 2D - Game Engine
                            [id] => 448835061804426
                        )

                    [message] => We're currently facing some server issues, hence the website being down, but we'll try to figure out the problem as soon as possible. 

Sorry for any inconvenience and thanks for your understanding :)
                    [privacy] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [value] => 
                        )

                    [type] => status
                    [status_type] => mobile_status_update
                    [created_time] => 2014-10-24T15:23:39+0000
                    [updated_time] => 2014-10-24T15:23:39+0000
                    [shares] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [count] => 1
                        )

                )
(...)
```

Let's say I want to loop through every post and retrieve the field **message**. I tried the following:

```
$content = $response->getGraphObject();
$pagefeed = $content->getProperty('data')->asArray();
foreach($pagefeed as $post) {
    echo $post->message;
}
```

It's showing the content of every message, but it's also raising an error:
**Undefined property: stdClass::$message**

http://abload.de/img/screenshot65ueuf.png

I believe I should be using getProperty, but it doesn't show anything that way.

**Edit**

Inside the foreach, I should check if the property is set or not, by using **isset**

Thanks

Comment: did you debug $pagefeed?

Comment: what do you mean with debug? Like I said, each message is being printed on the screen, but there's also the error I mentioned. Each message printed has that error above.

Comment: I've added a link of a screenshot to the main post

Comment: Ah damn, the problem is that the data retrieved has some elements which do not have message property. That said, I just had to check if it is set or not. Thanks!